# Writing a macro that generates a (cons atom (cons atom ... ))) list

Tags: elisp-macros

I am relatively new to elisp, and am currently in need of a macro that will take in a list, and return, not a cons-list, but:

given (1 2 3 4)

returns

(cons 1 (cons 2 (cons 3 4)))

Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: Are you looking for `cl-list*`? [`(cl) List Functions`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/cl/List-Functions.html)

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a macro for this.

```el
(defun foo (lst)
  (let ((last  (car (last lst)))
        (butl  (butlast lst)))
    (append butl last)))

(foo '(1 2 3 4)) ; ==> (1 2 3 . 4)
```